# Problems with Encoding in Eclipse Console and Python

Tags: python, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I guess I need some help regarding encodings in Python (2.6) and Eclipse. I used Google and the so-search and tried a lot of things but as a matter of fact I don't get it.

So, how do I achieve, that the output in the Eclipse console is able to show äöü etc.?

I tried:
Declaring the document encoding in the first line with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I changed the encoding settings in Window/Preferences/General/Workspace and Project/Properties to UTF-8

As nothing changed I tried the following things alone and in combination but nothing seemed to work out:

- Changing the stdout as mentioned in the Python Cookbook:

  sys.stdout = codecs.lookup("utf-8")-1
- Adding an unicode u:

print u"äöü".encode('UTF8')

- reloading sys (I don't know what for but it doesn't work either ;-))

I am trying to do this in order to debug the encoding-problems I have in my programs... (argh)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I work on Windows 7 and it is EasyEclipse

Comment: By adding a `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` you will set the encoding information which is then used by the Python parser to interpret the file using the given encoding [(See PEP 0263)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). So only interesting if you are using Umlauts in the source file. What do you see when you start the python interpreter on its own and `print 'üöä'`?

Comment: @robert-caspary In the interpreter I get a correct output äöü

Comment: Which console font are you using in eclipse? (Preferences -> General -> Appearance) At least on my Windows PC I could break my output for umlauts by using e.g. the Terminal font.

Comment: @robert-caspary Thanks for your help! Unfortunately: I changed the console font to Arial but still 'print "ö"' results in Ã¶

Comment: @robert-caspary no, `print 'ö'` gives `Ã¶`

Comment: Sry my typo. Please try `print repr( 'ö' )` and check if the output is `'\xc3\xb6'`

Comment: ah ok :-) yes, it's `'\xc3\xb6'`

Comment: Rather strange. Because that's the correct output. I assume you're german so maybe this [link](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Eclipse) is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it! If you have the same problem go to

`Run/Run Configurations/Common` and select the UTF-8 (e.g.) as console encoding.

So, finally, `print "ö"` results in `"ö"`

Answer (score 3):

Even this is a bit old question, I'm new in StackOverflow and I'd like to contribute a bit. You can change the default encoding in Eclipse  (currently Neon)  for the all text editors from the menu Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding

[Item Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjB5S.png)