# Python and EasyEclipse: identical code but results differ (encoding)

Tags: python, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I can't believe it. After I solved my question in [Problems with Encoding in Eclipse Console and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022937/problems-with-encoding-in-eclipse-console-and-python) I thought it wouldn't happen again that I got problems here. But now this:

I have a program test.py in the project TestMe that looks like this:

```
print "ö"
```

-> `Run as... Python Run` results in

```
ö
```

So far so good. When I now copy the program in EasyEclipse by right click/copy and paste I receive the program copy of test.py in the same project that looks exactly the same:

```
print "ö"
```

-> Bun `Run as... Python Run` results in

```
Ã¶
```

I noticed, that the file properties changed from Encoding UTF-8 to Default, but also changing to UTF-8 doesn't help here.
Another difference between the two files is the line ending which is "Windows" in the original file and "Unix" in the copy (great definition of copy, btw). Changing this in Notepad++ also doesn't change anything.

I am perplexed...

Set up:
Python 2.5
Windows 7
Easy Eclipse 1.2.2.2

Settings that I've set to UTF-8 / Windows: 
Project/Rightclick/Properties
File/Rightclick/Properties
Window/Preferences/Workspace

Comment: Several places to change the encoding, most immersive first: 1) Workspace `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace` 2) Project Properties 3) File Properties 4) Run Configuration. Using the first method is the most useful on as the others including the console inherit from it by default which is probably what you want.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to check explicitly the one I mentioned in the answer I refer to... many thanks! Would vote you up but this is just a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several places to change the encoding, most immersive first:

1. Workspace `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace`
2. Project Properties
3. File Properties
4. Run Configuration.

Using the first method is the most useful one as the others including the console inherit from it by default which is probably what you want.